# How to return to user menu at the end of a function in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I am writing a PowerShell script that gives the user a number of options to select from. Once an option is selected, a function is executed and the user is returned back to the original menu.

In the code below, the user is given the options, and the functions are executed, but when complete, the script just ends. What I want instead is at the end of the function to return to the original user menu. Can someone tell me how to do this? Thanks!

```
function firstFunction {
    Write-Host "You chose option 1"
    return
}

Write-Host "Welcome"

[int]$userMenuChoice = 0
while ( $userMenuChoice -lt 1 -or $userMenuChoice -gt 4){
    Write-Host "1. Menu Option 1"
    Write-Host "2. Menu Option 2"
    Write-Host "3. Menu Option 3"
    Write-Host "4. Quit and Exit"

[int]$userMenuChoice = Read-Host "Please choose an option"}
switch ($userMenuChoice) {
    1{firstFunction}
    2{Write-Host "You chose option 2"}
    3{Write-Host "You chose option 3"}
default {Write-Host "Nothing selected"}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the menu code into an outer loop that doesn't terminate unless `$userMenuChoice` is 4:

```
do {
  [int]$userMenuChoice = 0
  while ( $userMenuChoice -lt 1 -or $userMenuChoice -gt 4) {
    Write-Host "1. Menu Option 1"
    Write-Host "2. Menu Option 2"
    Write-Host "3. Menu Option 3"
    Write-Host "4. Quit and Exit"

    [int]$userMenuChoice = Read-Host "Please choose an option"

    switch ($userMenuChoice) {
      1{firstFunction}
      2{Write-Host "You chose option 2"}
      3{Write-Host "You chose option 3"}
      default {Write-Host "Nothing selected"}
    }
  }
} while ( $userMenuChoice -ne 4 )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. When i do what you suggest, the program gets stuck in an infinite loop inside the selected function. How do I tell the function to return to the menu when run once?

Comment: My mistake. There was a spurious closing curly bracket in the `Read-Host` line, and the code didn't reset `$userMenuChoice` before displaying the menu again. Fixed.