# Powershell Script Active Directory

Tags: powershell

need some pointers on how to construct a Powershell script that does the following things : asks for active directory username, gives a menu to enable these active directory actions given for username :Reset password, Disable user account, Enable user account, Unlock user account, Delete user account?

Answer (score 1):

To ask a user for input, try `Read-Host`. Ex:

```
$username = Read-Host "Type in username"
```

There are many ways to create a menu. You could do it manually using `Write-Host` to show info and `Read-Host` + a `switch`-statement to execute the chosen answer. Or you could use the built-in solution with [`$host.ui.PromptForChoice()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface.promptforchoice(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.host.choicedescription(v=vs.85).aspx)-objects (one per menu item).

Menu examples:

- Using the built-in menu-classes/-solution: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730939.aspx
- Simple manually created menu: [How to return to user menu at the end of a function in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625086/how-to-return-to-user-menu-at-the-end-of-a-function-in-powershell)